# Multiple visualization with different time-frames

Tags: kibana-4

I'd like to present - on the same dashboard - multiple visualizations with different timeframes: for example: yesterday's data side-by-side with today's data.

This appears to be impossible - or at the very least I can't find this option. Setting the time-frame on the top of the dashboard sets the time for ALL visualizations.

Is this feature supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK: this appear to be impossible at the moment.

According to this github issue this feature is not supported but might be one day :/

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3578